# Powershell Script assistance required

Tags: powershell

I'm piping a file's contents to Select-Object and creating two properties for each name, `ComputerName` and `FileExists`, where the latter value is the result of `Test-Path`

```
Get-Content c:\Users\Admin\Documents\Scripts\Serverlist.txt | `
   Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$_}},@{Name='FolderExist';Expression={ Test-Path "\\$_\c$\Data\Repository"}},
@{Name='Size';Expression={$_.Sum}}
```

I want to return the size of this folder if it exists on each server. How would you do it ?

Tried adding

```
@{Name='Size';Expression={$_.Sum}}
```

to my `select-object` but that does not return any value

Answer (score 0):

Since at least one calculated property depends on the other, you would have to do at least 2 `Select-Object` statements, but I would probably use `ForEach-Object` and `New-Object` instead:

```
Get-Content c:\Users\Admin\Documents\Scripts\Serverlist.txt | ForEach-Object {
  New-Object psobject -Property @{
    'ComputerName' = $_
    'FileExists' = ($FileExists = Test-Path ($FilePath = "\\$_\c$\Data\repository"))
    'Size' = if($FileExists){ (Get-Item $FilePath).Length } else { $null }
  }
}
```

`(Get-Item $FilePath).Length` won't get you far if `C:\Data\repository` is a directory, but you can substitute your own statement inside the if block

For the sake of my future coworkers I would probably avoid doing a one-liner like your example, and write multiple statements like so:

```
Get-Content c:\Users\Admin\Documents\Scripts\Serverlist.txt | ForEach-Object {

  $ComputerName = $_

  $FilePath = "\\$ComputerName\c$\Data\repository"
  $FileExists = Test-Path $FilePath

  if($FileExists){
    $Size = Get-Item $FilePath | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Length
  } else {
    $Size = $null
  }

  New-Object psobject -Property @{
    'ComputerName' = $ComputerName
    'FileExists'   = $FileExists
    'Size'         = $Size
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
  Get-Content c:\Users\Admin\Documents\Scripts\Serverlist.txt | Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$_}},@{Name='FolderExist';Expression={ Test-Path "\\$_\c$\Data\Repository"}}, @{Name='Size';Expression={ "{0:n2}" -f ((gci -path "\\$_\c$\Data\Repository" -recurse | measure-object -property length -sum).sum /1mb) + " mb" }}
```